# Rest api endpoint works when run locally, but not in docker container. (Quarkus/Jax-rs resteasy)

Tags: java, jax-rs, quarkus

I have a simple endpoint like so.

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response registerPayment(Payment payment) throws Exception {

    try {
    DTUPayAccount customer = new DTUPayAccount();
    DTUPayAccount merchant = new DTUPayAccount();
    TransactionLog transaction;


    String customerId = tokenManagement.validateToken(payment.getToken());

    customer.setBankID(accountManagement.getDtuPayAccount(customerId).getBankID());

    merchant.setBankID(accountManagement.getDtuPayAccount(payment.getMerchantDtuPayID()).getBankID());

    bank.addPayment(customer.getBankID(), merchant.getBankID(), payment.getAmount(), "Added payment");

    transaction = new TransactionLog(
            customerId,
            payment.getMerchantDtuPayID(),
            payment.getToken(),
            payment.getAmount()
    );

    transactionLog.StoreTransaction(transaction);
    return Response.status(201).entity("The payment was succesful").build();

    } catch (Exception err) {
        return Response.status(400).entity(err.getMessage()).build();
    }
}
```

When I run my api locally in dev mode, it correctly returns a 201 status code. However, when I run it in a docker container and send the exact same data in the body of my request, I get a 500 internal server error.

My dockerfile

```
FROM adoptopenjdk:11-jre-hotspot
WORKDIR /usr/src
COPY target/code-with-quarkus-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-runner.jar /usr/src
CMD java -Xmx64m \
-jar code-with-quarkus-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-runner.jar
```

Now I don't even know where to begin looking for a possible cause for this, but does anyone have an idea where it might make sense to look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The runner jar is not the full app. You also need to copy the `lib/` directory.

You should have an example Docker file in `src/main/docker` if you have scaffolded your application with our tools.

You can find the template here: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/blob/master/devtools/platform-descriptor-json/src/main/resources/templates/dockerfile-jvm.ftl .

And an example here: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus-bot-java/blob/master/src/main/docker/Dockerfile.jvm .